# Conditionally switch out jQuery methods?

Tags: jquery

I have some text that I want to slide up and down under one circumstance but fade in and out under a different circumstance.

At the moment I'm doing this:

```
var text1 = $('.text1'),
    text2 = $('.text2');

if (conditionIsTrue){
    if (text1.is(':hidden')) {
        text2.slideUp();
        text1.slideDown();

    } else if (text2.is(':hidden')) {
        text1.slideUp();
        text2.slideDown();
    }
} else {
    if (text1.is(':hidden')) {
        text2.fadeOut();
        text1.fadeIn();

    } else if (text2.is(':hidden')) {
        text1.fadeOut();
        text2.fadeIn();
    }
}
```

There is ugly code repetition in there though. Is there a way to do it without the code repetition?

Answer (score 0):

I found a great solution to this :)

```
    var fadeSlideMethod = conditionIsTrue ? 'slide' : 'fade',
        text1 = $('.text1'),
        text2 = $('.text2');;

    //lets you dynamically pick if you want to use jQueries slide or fade animation
    $.fn.fadeOrSlide = function(method, inOrOut) {
        var _this = this;
        var functionality = {
            slide : {
                'in' : function(){
                     _this.slideDown();
                },
                'out' : function(){
                    _this.slideUp();
                }
            },
            fade : {
                'in' : function(){
                     _this.fadeIn();
                },
                'out' : function(){
                    _this.fadeOut();
                }
            }
        };
        functionality[method][inOrOut]();
    }

    if (text1.is(':hidden')) {
        text2.fadeOrSlide(fadeSlideMethod,'out');
        text1.fadeOrSlide(fadeSlideMethod,'in');

    } else if (text2.is(':hidden')) {
        text1.fadeOrSlide(fadeSlideMethod,'out');
        text2.fadeOrSlide(fadeSlideMethod,'in');
    }
```